# Не выходит подключиться к FTP Android

Tags: java, android, ftp

Есть метод подключения к FTP

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password, int port)
    {
        boolean status = false;

        Log.d("myLog", "host " + host + " username " + username + " password " + password + " port "+ port);

        try
        {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            Log.d("myLog", "Код ответа" + mFTPClient.getReplyCode());

            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode()))
            {
                status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            }

            Log.d("myLog", "Все прошло успешно");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("myLog", "Error: could not connect to host " + host + " " + e);
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Пытаюсь подключиться, но не выдается, почему без понятия, думал, что не верно ввожу данные йп логина и пароля, сделал вывод в дебаг и все верно. в FTP клиентах все работает отлично.

Comment: А что выводиться в лог?

Comment: 07-22 23:05:37.877 14015-14015/ru.landmarkstd.educt D/myLog: host ***** username **** password ***** port 21
07-22 23:05:37.892 14015-14015/ru.landmarkstd.educt D/myLog: Error: could not connect to host 78.108.80.117 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-22 23:05:37.892 14015-14015/ru.landmarkstd.educt D/myLog: false FtpConnect

Comment: вот Ваша проблема - "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". - нельзя в главном потоке делать сетевые запросы.

Comment: Тоесть выносить все в asynctask ?

Comment: или отдельный тред. -  в интернете много статей на эту тему.